# FastMM suddenly reports memory leaks in Graphics32

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I have an empty project (it contains just a form). If I add this line to the project 'USES GR32_Image;' and run the application, FastMM shows leak in the program. FastMM is set to full debug. There is NO code in my program - except what Delphi IDE generates and except the 'uses gr32' line.

The report makes no sense. 
Here is the full log: http://pastebin.com/Yhev3rJ2
And here is the source code: http://pastebin.com/VjRrRiS8

I have used the Graphics32 unit before and I never had problems. Why I have this leak and why FastMM cannot generate a proper report?

Comment: Could you post your code so that we can help. You should be able to put something together in just a single .dpr file that will exhibit the problem.

Comment: @Altar Why are you not getting function names in your stack trace? I think you need to configure FastMM correctly. Also, it has just occurred to me that perhaps these memory leaks are expected ones from the VCL.

Comment: @David: That looks like FullDebugMode is on and FastMM is configured properly, but it's got no map file to look up the addresses against.  If he had the linker generate detailed map files it would become a lot clearer what was going on.

Comment: Just adding the file you're talking about to the project won't cause a memory leak. Not atleast using the latest version, I downloaded and tried it. Are you even sure that Graphics32 is causing this? Yes, TFunctionRegistry is part of Graphics32, but that might just mean that your code is leaking. There is no Initialization section in GR32_Image. Please do what Mason suggests, Project Options->Linker->Map File Detailed (BDS2006).

Comment: @Altar Why can't you condense your entire code into a simple .dpr file? No need to include a .dfm file.

Comment: There is NO code in my program - except what Delphi IDE generates and except the 'uses gr32' line.

Comment: @altar is the gr32 uses before or after the fastmm uses in the dpr?

Comment: Hi David. FastMM is the first thing in the DPR file. Then the 'USES GR32_Image' line is the main form's unit, so it is after FastMM.

Comment: I have posted also the source code to reproduce the error: http://pastebin.com/VjRrRiS8

Comment: @Altar That runs without leaks for me on D6 (I don't have D7 at hand but I don't imagine it is any different). I do get leaks but they are all expected and known leaks in the VCL rather than GR32 leaks. What version of GR32 are you using? What modifications have you made to the GR32 code? Could you try downloading GR32 again and checking how it works with unmodified GR32.

Comment: Hi David. This is EXACTLY what I was testing. I just remembered that some days ago (maybe one week) I recompiled GR32 but I forgot the reason. So I went there and compared the original GR32 code with my GR32 code and I have found this extra line: {$D-} in GR32.INC file. I think I put that line in order to make the debugger not to step into GR32 code. I removed the line and it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile your app with full debug info, then in the linker options, make sure your debug info is in the .EXE and/or .MAP file.

Then run FastMM with FullDebugMode, and copy/paste the resulting .TXT file in your question.

See also [this post](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/) for more tips.

**Edit:**

A good first step is to do something like this on your .TXT file:

```
find "The allocation number is" < fastmmlog.txt | sort /R
```

That gives you the first allocation number, in your case `281`.

From that, you search in the .TXT for the allocation number:

```
--------------------------------2011/1/7 23:31:03--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0x1540, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
402D80 [System][System][@GetMem]
40388F [System][System][TObject.NewInstance]
403C12 [System][System][@ClassCreate]
4038C4 [System][System][TObject.Create]
403C12 [System][System][@ClassCreate]
403C6A [System][System][@AfterConstruction]
457922 [GR32_Bindings][GR32_Bindings][NewRegistry]
45807E [GR32_LowLevel][GR32_LowLevel][RegisterBindings]
458152 [GR32_LowLevel][GR32_LowLevel][GR32_LowLevel]
404373 [System][System][InitUnits]
4043DB [System][System][@StartExe]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TList

The allocation number is: 281
```

Here you can see, that the `NewRegistry` is involved in your leak.
From there, you can start debugging to find out why it leaks.

--jeroen

Comment: Hi Jeroen. I just did that. Please see the original post. I had to cut a big part from log because the posts are limited to 30000 chars.

Comment: Put your full .txt online at http://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/ so people van view the full thing.

Comment: I pasted the full log and source code. Please see the original post when possible.

Comment: Answer accepted (it answers the "why FastMM cannot generate a proper report" question). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Enable FullDebugMode if your using the full version of FastMM4. Also turn on detailed map generation to help with the stack trace. Check the unit initialization section of that unit and see if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Both issues solved.

1. I remembered that some time ago I added this line of code in GR32.inc:
   {$D-}
   I removed the line, recompiled the VCL and it worked. Totally my fault.
2. See Jeroen Pluimers post which answer the question "why FastMM cannot generate a proper report?"

---

Thanks to all for participating.

Comment: good to hear that you are sorted but you could have given the rep to someone other than yourself!

Comment: You have only comments and no stand alone answer. From what I know I cannot vote a comment as solution to the problem. Sorry.

Comment: I know, but I didn't actually mean that I should get the rep. Others earnt it too, and I see that you have now given it to Jeroen. Also, did you get what you needed with your IMAGE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE question?